# How can I make a dynamic route in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, multi-tenant

I need make a dynamic route or dynamic subdomain for multitenant site. I am not sure the better option. The matter is when the user create the account should get a URI like:

http://www.domain.dom/username

or

http://username.domain.com

I am not expert so I prefer the easiest way to do that. Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your routes like this:

```php
// First example
Route::get('{username}', 'MyController@myAction');

// Second example
Route::group(['domain' => '{username}.domain.com'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'MyController@myAction');
});
```

Please note that you still have to set up your webserver to listen to all urls.

More info on subdomain routing can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing